# Spring Boot 2 - Some Graphite Metrics not receiving common tags from customizer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am using Spring Boot 2 + Graphite reporting and have some metrics that are receiving common tags, and some that are not.

I have two beans that are identical except for the name, both creating a timer with the same code. One of them is created first and does not have commonTags applied, the other does. e.g.,

```
@Autowired
MeterRegistry meterRegistry

@Bean Foo doesNotGetCommonTags() {
    meterRegistry.timer(...);
    ...
}

@Bean MeterRegistryCustomizer<GraphiteMeterRegistry> graphiteCustomizer() {
   return r -> r.config().commonTags(...);
}

@Bean Foo getsCommonTags() {
    meterRegistry.timer(...);
    ...
}
```

It seems to have to do with bean creation order, but I cannot figure out how to ensure my registry is fully customised before creating meters. I’m using the common tags as a prefix, so this results in some metrics being send to Graphite unprefixed, while others are.

I don’t understand what could cause this. My graphiteCustomizer should be applied before the metrics registry is injected, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround (which I don’t consider a full solution) was to not use `MeterRegsitryCustomizer` and instead create the Graphite registry myself with my desired customisations.